# viewport is ignored when using php $this->beginBody() and endBody()

Tags: php, html, css, yii, viewport

I am trying to make my website mobile friendly and it works when using inside head

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<?php $this->head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/_top_js'); ?>
<?= Alert::flashes() ?>
<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/_header'); ?>
<?= $content ?>
<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/_footer'); ?>
<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/_bottom_js'); ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

But when I start using the following code:

```
php $this->beginBody() 
php $this->endBody()
```

it is completely ignored.  Is the viewport code disabled when using the php code to load my pages?

Comment: PHP only outputs text, it has no effect on how the site appears in a browser. Check that your views are returning proper HTML

Comment: I am getting proper HTML but the screen size does not shrink to mobile device's size when using php beginBody.  I have this as the main layout for my site so that headers and footers are the same for every page.  Everypage is managed by siteController.php

Answer (score 0):

The viewport needs to be explicitly set in the `<head>` section of your HTML. You should start the page with `beginPage()` instead of `beginBody()`, as the second one only renders the `<body></body>` part of the HTML.

PHP only outputs HTML on the page, in the case of Yii using [layouts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts).
You need to check your layout files to make sure they contain the following line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I am already using `beginPage()`  followed by:

`<head>`  
`<?<?php $this->head(); ?>`  
`/<head>`  
`<body>`  
`<?php $this->beginBody() ?>`  
`<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/_header'); ?>`  
`<?php echo $this->render('//layouts/_footer'); ?>`  
`<?php $this->endBody() ?>`  
`</body>`  
`</html>`  
`<?php $this->endPage() ?>`

Comment: Then check the output HTML of your script near `$this->head();`. Does it contain the viewport `<meta>`?

Comment: I updated my code on the post, this head does contain the viewport.  When I delete the beginBody() and endBody() I get just text on my web pages.  I have several pages and they all use the `<?= $content ?>` part.